# how to load the google maps API only when my app is navigator.onLine?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

How can I add some javascript which only loads the google maps api:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

when my app is online (`navigator.onLine == true`)?

Comment: Will the script not load _only_ when you are online anyway?

Comment: yes but then I will get a error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic script insertion:

```
if(navigator.onLine) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  //You must use the callback parameter when loading the script asynchronously
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  scripts[0].parentNode.insertBefore(script, scripts[0]);
}

function initialize() {
  //initialize map here
}
```

See the [Asynchronous Loading topic](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async) in the [Google Maps API v3 Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

You might also be interested in [Google Maps API v3: Developing for Mobile Devices](http://blogs.missouristate.edu/web/2010/05/12/google-maps-api-v3-developing-for-mobile-devices/)